# how to use array as function variable in bash

Tags: bash

I want to pass an array parameter to a function in bash, and writing some testing code as：

```
 #!/bin/sh

    function foo {
       a=$1;
       for i in ${a[@]} ; do
          echo $i
       done
    }
    names=(jim jerry jeff)
    foo ${names[@]}
```

the above code just show jim, rather than the three j*. so my question is:

- why my code doesn't work
- what's the right way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
my_array[0]="jim"
my_array[1]="jerry"

function foo
{
    #get the size of the array
    n=${#my_array[*]}
    for (( Idx = 0; Idx < $n; ++Idx  )); do
            echo "${my_array[$Idx]}"
    done
}
```

Comment: thanks but I want to get a local copy of the array to prevent the original one being changed

Comment: Did you try to pass it to the function with the '$' like : foo ${names} ?

Comment: Sorry about that but in the above example you do not do that correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
function foo {
a=($*)
for i in ${a[@]}
do
    echo $i
done
}

names=(jim jerry jeff)
foo ${names[@]}
```

Your code did not show jim to me, but "names", literally. You have to pass the whole array. And you have to recapture it with `a=$($)`.

The manpage part in bash about Arrays is rather long. I only cite one sentence:

> Referencing an  array  variable  without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

Comment: @HaiyuanZhang: Btw.: When using the bash, use the Bash-Shebang.

Answer (score 2):

You're fairly close; the biggest problem was the command `a=$1`, which assigns only the first parameter (`$1`) to `a`, while you want to assign the entire list of parameters (`$@`), and assign it as an array rather than as a string.  Other things I corrected: you should use double-quotes around variables whenever you use them to avoid confusion with special characters (e.g. spaces); and start the script with `#!/bin/bash`, since arrays are a bash extension, not always available in a brand-X shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

function foo {
    a=("$@")
    for i in "${a[@]}" ; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}

names=(jim jerry jeff "jim bob")
foo "${names[@]}"
```